# What's causing certain PHP function names to crash PHP?

Tags: php

I was programming a client user database this afternoon when I noticed PHP starting to crash without a parse error -- in what I can only assume was a segmentation fault. I tried narrowing down the problem until I realized when I renamed certain functions, they would stop crashing. This is the most bizarre PHP bug I've ever encountered. Here are some of the function names causing the problem:

create_user_account() - crashes
renamed to create_user_email() - works
check_user_email() - crashes
renamed to check_user_account() - works

I'm at a total loss on what could be causing this error. Any help in tracing the issue or diagnosing the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the create_user_account and check_user_email are unique?

Comment: don't be so quick to call it a PHP bug

Comment: Step 1: enabled full error-reporting & logging (by _settings_, not in-script). Any errors?

Comment: You don't think crashing is a bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
function foo() {}
```

works! But now:

```
function foo() {}
function foo() {}
```

crashes! Oh! Let's rename the function:

```
function foo() {}
function foo2() {}
```

Works! Yay! Works! Happy day!!!! Sing and Dance!

---

To make a long story short: This calls for basic debugging first - which code is hit when the screen is blank? Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log. And at that stage then: Which part of the error message do you not understand in specific?

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on a very limited shared hosting setup, but I'll try that.

Comment: Well you can do debugging step by step, e.g. there is [`function_exists`](http://php.net/function_exists).

Comment: Weird! function_exists indicate the functions causing the problem already exist, but... they don't! I'm working in a PHP file with only a couple of lines. I guess it's out of my hands and I should report this to the host.

Comment: Use PHP's reflection to find out in which file it is defined. You probably include some file twice.

Comment: That's the thing. I'm not including any files. I'm just working with an empty PHP file with everything removed except for the function declaration. I'll check out reflection and see if I can find it.

Comment: In case this is any help to anyone at a later time, Reflection is finding the function in a different PHP file which is **not** being included. Strange, but I think that solves the problem for now.

Comment: Not included? Check with [`get_included_files`](http://php.net/get_included_files), you should find it in the list.

Comment: Thanks for helping me figure this out. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time you probably want to do some basic debugging first. Whenever you wonder about something, try to find out what exactly is happening. Start to get an error message for example, those are very useful.